# How to get data and pass it into a method from a created object in Java

Tags: java, object, constructor

I'm having troubles with creating a shopping app in java. I have product.java file with a constructor

```
public Product(String nameIn, int stockLevelIn, double priceIn) {
        name = nameIn;
        stockLevel = stockLevelIn;
        price = priceIn;
    }
```

and I wanted to create an object in a different file called ShopApp.java

```
String[] productsSold = { "TV", "Sofa", "Iphone", "Sneakers", "Ball" };
        Product prod1 = new Product(productsSold[0], 50, 499.99);
        Product prod2 = new Product(productsSold[1], 30, 299.99);
        Product prod3 = new Product(productsSold[2], 100, 399.99);
        Product prod4 = new Product(productsSold[3], 800, 500.99);
        Product prod5 = new Product(productsSold[4], 20, 100.99);
```

and the question is, how could I get "50" stockLevelIn from e.g prod1 and use it somewhere?
I wanted it to use to update the stock number after someone buys the product
Thank you in advance

Comment: @g00se all works, thank you kindly! thanks for all the info!

Comment: OK, shall make it the answer for you to accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Java classes should have getters and setters for private variables, so the answer would be - "call `getStockLevel`". Or if you want to reset the level, `setStockLevel`
btw you don't need to invent different parameter names in ctors and setters. Just use `this.stockLevel = stockLevel`